# parameter substitution template plugin

Tags: substitute

I would like to find a plugin, what can do the following in normal mode of vim:

- Parameter initialization
- Parameter substitution into text based on templates

Suppose we have many sql query where `country_code` can change but the other conditions are always the same :

```
select * from customers c where c.id= ... c.country_code=36 
select * from product p where p.name= ... p.country_code=36
.... several other query with ... country_code=36
```

So, the plugin can replace the `:cc` to `36` and result can be on the clipboard, or buffer but I dont want to touch the original queries, i want to keep them as templates.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you simply write your file to another one (if you don't want to modify the original) and simply use a substitution command (e.g. `%s/country_code=/\036`) and then simply yank the desired line? You don't even have to write your file to a temporary one you can simply do the substitution, yank your command and then quit vim without saving your file.

Comment: I think vim can solve it in one page with buffers, thats why I think there should be a plugin.

Comment: But I think I gave you a solution in my previous comment which doesn't need a plugin. What you want to do sounds pretty specific so I'm not sure someone already wrote a plugin which will do exactly what you want. You'd be better using built-in functions.

Comment: What do you want to do with the result after the plugin places it in the clipboard/new buffer?

Comment: the result can be run in the commad prompt with !, so I can use parameterized command line commands. e.g not long before my colleagues and me type the following sql query min 20 times per day : select * from foo where port=62017 and date=2017-10-01 and .... but other conditions were the same. e.g Squirrel SQL client knows this feature. I want do this in more generalized form. I can do this kind of parameterizing with bash script as well, but I dont want to hide the details into function

Comment: Looks like to me that any snippets/template engine can do the substitution automatically. These plugins should even be able to let you enter the country code manually, or to fetch them automatically anywhere else.

Comment: Okay, with those requirements, and if you didn't want to just use a snippet engine as @LucHermitte suggests, I'd write a function/mapping to read the current line, prompt the user for the parameter replacements, and then actually run the command. It wouldn't be much code, but there so many slightly different ways it could work that I think the best person to write it is you!

Comment: Hello Rich, I started to learn the vim scripting to solve this problem, thanks for your offer, but Im going to try to write vim script by myself, I really appreciate your offer.

Comment: Hey Luc, thanks for your suggestion, I checked some snippet engine, but I cant see clearly whether this function exists or not, so Im going to do it by myself